# How do I delete selected documents in a XPage Dynamic View Panel

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I created a Dynamic View Panel. I have check boxes on. I have called this "dynamicViewPanel1" and I have set the Data Source name to "dViewData"

So far so good, everything works fine.

Now I created a button called "Delete" and set it to a simple action of delete selected documents and set the view control to "dViewData".

When I select one or more documents and click delete I get the following error.

javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find target view control dViewData. I take it because the data source is wrapped inside the Dynamic View panel?

I've checked the documentation, but I can't see how get the button to recognize the selected documents. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you see and try this? 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/2008-11-11033022WEBBZ4.htm

```
var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");get the componet of viewPanel
var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); get the array of document ids
for(i=0;
i < docIDArray.length;
i++){
    var docId=docIDArray[i];
    var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId);
    .. your code to deal with the selected document
}
```

(I think the code above only handle view panels in the current database though)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! So to delete I used with that code: doc.remove(true);doc.recycle();