# Changing multiple data in a view

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I need help using Xpages. If there vas a question like this or there is an example can you tell me where to find it.
I have a main page that contains several rows and columns, like this

```
[Checkbox][Column1][Column2][Column3][Column 4][Column 5]
[Checkbox][Data1][Data2][Data3][Data4][Data5]
[Checkbox][Data1][Data2][Data3][Data4][Data5]
[Checkbox][Data1][Data2][Data3][Data4][Data5]
[Checkbox][Data1][Data2][Data3][Data4][Data5]
[Checkbox][Data1][Data2][Data3][Data4][Data5]
```

Now Data 5 is a default value and it is Undefined, the only values other that it can be set is to „Do“ or „Do not“. Is there a way to Chek several rows for which i vant to change the value to Do or Do not in Data 5 using combobox and save button, without going into detail view of the data.

For example, i have 30 rows that have Data 5 set to undefined, and i want 10 of them to set to Do. I just chek them in checkbox, select in combobox Do and press Save. So i don't have to endet evry row and edit them one by one.

Comment: For inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528947/how-do-i-delete-selected-documents-in-a-xpage-dynamic-view-panel

Answer (score 2):

Adapt the XSnippet [Simple "Trash" Folder c/w Selectable Rows & Restore Functionality](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=simple-trash-folder-cw-selectable-rows-restore-functionality) to your needs.

```xml
  <xp:comboBox
      id="comboBox1"
      value="#{viewScope.DoOrDont}">
      <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Do"></xp:selectItem>
      <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Do not"></xp:selectItem>
  </xp:comboBox>
  <xp:button id="button4" value="Change selected rows">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
      refreshMode="complete">
      <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
          var vp1 = getComponent("viewPanel1");
          if(null != vp1){
              var dm:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel = vp1.getDataModel();
              if(null != dm){
                  var idsIter = dm.getSelectedIds();
                  while(null != idsIter && idsIter.hasNext()){
                       var id = idsIter.next();
                       if(null != id){
                           var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByID(id);
                           if(null != doc){
                               doc.replaceItemValue("yourField", viewScope.DoOrDont);
                               doc.save();
                           }
                       }
                  }
              }
          }}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
  </xp:button>
```

The example contains a combobox where you can select "Do" or "Do not" and a button which sets this value to all selected documents.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the whole picture of your requirements, but here is one way to do it.

When you "tick" a checkbox, use the server side "onclick" event to set a sessionScope containing the noteid and include any value you want to update the document with. set the refresh id to the checkbox.

For each checkbox the user ticks, a new noteid is added to the sessionScope.
When the user is ready to save the changes using the save button, loop the unids in the sessionScope and update the documents in the background and clear the sessionScope

Using this approach you can also provide a "next" page that show all the documents in the scope and allow the user to confirm the save

you might also want to add a keepalive so the users scope is not discarded

Answer (score 0):

The best way for that is to combine client side and server side code. Here is what I would do in this case :

1. Add a StyleClass to the checkboxes. In order to do so click on a checkbox, go to all properties and find StyleClass in the list. For example let's put this class name : `myCheckboxClass`. With this class name you will be able to retrieve easily all the checkboxes checked on the client.
2. Add also a custom attribute to the checkboxes that contains the unid of the document related to the row. To do so click on a checkbox, go to all properties again and find attr. Add a new attr called for example `unid` and compute its value to be the unid of the row. This attribute will allow you to know from the client to which document this checkbox is linked to.
3. Now on your save button, with a **client side script**, you can really easily get all the documents to modify with the following :

   ```
   var documentsToUpdate = [];
   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myCheckboxClass");
   for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
       var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
       if (checkbox.checked) {
           documentsToUpdate.push[checkbox.getAttribute("unid")];
       }
   }

   // Send the array, in a JSON format, to the server
   return XSP.toJson(documentsToUpdate);
   ```
4. Now on your save button, with this time the **server side script**, retrieve the information from the client, and use the array of unids to change the value you want in the selected documents :

   ```
   // Get the return value from the client
   var jsonDocumentsToUpdate = context.getSubmittedValue();

   // Change the JSON into an array
   var documentsToUpdate = fromJson(jsonDocumentsToUpdate);

   // Go through the array and update the documents
   for (var i = 0; i < documentsToUpdate.length; i++) {
       var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(documentsToUpdate[i]);
       // DO YOUR CHANGES
       doc.save();
   }
   ```

Now you have everything to do what you need. You just have to check what the user chose in the combo box and to do the proper changes according to it. I think it's really important to learn this approach combining client side and server side code, that can be apply a lot in Xpages to do what you want quickly.